# Eigenvalue problems in finite volume

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Does every eigenvalue problem of a selfadjoint operator which should be solved in a finite volume have a discrete set of eigenvalues (no matter it is treated classically or in a quantum mechanical approach)?

Comment: This might depend on the assumed boundary conditions and whether it can be reduced to Sturm-Liouville problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is "physically" obvious from explicitly solvable examples.

The mathematical proof for the Laplace operator with a more general boundary is nontrivial.

[This paper](http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/voli/2/nica.pdf), as I understand it, shows by a min-max argument that an nondecreasing sequence of eigenvectors exists and then using the "Rellich compactness theorem" proves (p.29) that the sequence is unbounded.

See also [How to prove Weyl’s asymptotic law for the eigenvalues of the Dirichlet Laplacian?(math.stackexchange)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40115/how-to-prove-weyl-s-asymptotic-law-for-the-eigenvalues-of-the-dirichlet-laplacia?noredirect=1&lq=1) .